# RegEx for replacing non-dash chars matching an array of strings

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I have a few constants defined in PHP and I consider them private and shouldn't be displayed in the browser.

```php
const PRIV_API_KEY = '1234-5678-8426';
const PRIV_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'fnse0segh-23hfoeghl-fseuhosz';
...
```

If I have a string like so

```php
$message = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet 1234-5678-8426 bibendum id et dolor.';
```

Where the `1234-5678-8426` could be any of the constants I mentioned above. I would like to replace all characters except the dashes (`-`) if they match any of the private constants.

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet ****-****-**** bibendum id et dolor.
```

---

So far, I have only come as far as coming up with a regex to replace non-dash characters.

```php
$message = preg_replace('/[^-]/', '*', $message);
```

The problem with my current solution is that it replaces ALL non-dash characters even if they don't match any of the private constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do what you want. This code finds all your `PRIV*` constants using [`get_defined_constants`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) and [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), converts them into regexes using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), and then uses [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to replace all occurrences of the constants in a string with `*` other than `-` characters:

```
const PRIV_API_KEY = '1234-5678-8426';
const PRIV_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'fnse0segh-23hfoeghl-fseuhosz';
const NONPRIV_CONST = 42;

$priv_constants = array_filter(get_defined_constants(true)['user'], function ($k) { return substr($k, 0, 4) == 'PRIV'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$regexes = array_map(function ($v) { return '/' . preg_quote($v) . '/' ; }, $priv_constants);

$message = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet 1234-5678-8426 bibendum id et dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor fnse0segh-23hfoeghl-fseuhosz sit ammet bibendum id et dolor.';

$message = preg_replace_callback($regexes, function ($m) { return preg_replace('/[^-]/', '*', $m[0]); }, $message);
echo $message;
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet ****-****-**** bibendum id et dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor *********-*********-******** sit ammet bibendum id et dolor.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eMOiE)

Comment: Wow, okay - sure it isn't a one-liner but it looks promising. Let me test it out for a few minutes and I'll mark as the answer if I don't find any issues with it. Thanks!

Comment: @dokgu you could combine all the code into one line but it would be pretty messy! :-) If you don't mind hard-wiring an array of the constants you can remove the lines generating `$priv_constants` and `$regexes`. I was just trying to give you something completely flexible.